# Could not initialize class org.apache.pulsar.jetty.tls.JettySslContextFactory

Tags: java-11, apache-pulsar, protobuf-java, wildfly-26

Could not initialize class org.apache.pulsar.jetty.tls.JettySslContextFactory

<pulsar-client.version>2.10.1</pulsar-client.version>

<dependency>

<groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>

<artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>

<version>3.22.0</version>

</dependency>

what are the compactible version of apache pulsar , protbuf & wildfly 26 ?